# Linux's write command issue

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to send a message to myself through `write` command because I want some scripts running in the background and being able to echo things to the terminal where I am.

So, I get always the same error and I don't know what else to try:

```
user $: mesg y
user $: mesg
is y
user $: write myuser
write: myuser has messages disabled
echo 'hello' | write myuser
write: myuser has messages disabled
myuser $DISPLAY
write: myuser has messages disabled
echo 'hello' | write myuser $DISPLAY
write: myuser has messages disabled
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

PS: I get same results as root.

Comment: Please run `cat /etc/default/devpts` and show the results.  Also, please run `/bin/mount | grep devpts` and copy the results here.  Lastly, which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: `cat: /etc/default/devpts: No such file or directory`. I'm running on Gentoo. The second command prompts this: `devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)`

Comment: OK.   `gid=5,mode=620` are the values required, as per `man mount`, for enabling `mesg`.   They are the values that I have and your command above, `echo 'hello' | write myuser`, works fine for me.  I hope someone else has ideas that will help you.

Comment: @John1024 No problem dude, your comment pointed me to the right answer ^^.

Comment: Excellent.  `write` gave me a warnings such as `logged in more than once; writing to pts/1` but continued to work without my needing to specify a pts.

Comment: LoL, I don't really understand what pts are and how to handle them, it works for me when I use pts/13 but the output's command goes to the terminal I have with irssi and it breaks my irssi's layout. I think i have a research work in here XD. PS: I also don't understand why it doesn't work for me when I don't specify pts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, ##linux channel on freenet network and `man mesg` I found the answer, which is:

```
myuser $: w
 18:45:42 up 17:00,  2 users,  load average: 4.10, 3.84, 3.52
 USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
 myuser :0.0      01:46   ?xdm?  23:59   0.02s /usr/bin/ck-launch-session /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/i3

myuser $: sudo login myuser
 Password: 
 Last login: Sun Apr 26 18:18:43 CEST 2015 on pts/6

myuser $: w
 18:46:31 up 17:00,  3 users,  load average: 4,11, 3,89, 3,56
 USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
 myuser :0.0      01:46   ?xdm?  24:13   0.02s /usr/bin/ck-launch-session /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/i3
 myuser pts/1     18:46    7.00s  0.86s  0.00s w

myuser $: echo "Now it works! :). Thanks to John1024 from http://superuser.com and <arvut> from ##linux channel in freenode's network :)" | write myuser /dev/pts/1

  Message of myuser@tux the pts/1 at 18:50 ...
  Now it works! :). Thanks to John1024 from http://superuser.com and <arvut> from ##linux channel in freenode's network :)
  EOF
```

This happened to me just because I'm using a minimalistic graphical setup, it won't happen if you use any normal Desktop Environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command

```
who -T
```

in your script to determine which port to use for writing.  The '+' or '-' character indicates whether the terminal is writable.

```
[lion@FedoraXXI ~]$ who -T
lion     ? :0           2015-04-24 15:18 (:0)
lion     + pts/0        2015-04-24 19:58 (:0)
lion     - pts/1        2015-04-24 21:24 (:0)
[lion@FedoraXXI ~]$
```

Comment: the output of `who -T` is `vdevatman ? :0.0         2015-04-23 23:09 (:0.0)` for me and the output of just `who` is the same but without the `?` I don't know why, but it doesn't seems to be as useful as in your case.

Comment: Now that it is solved, the output of the command you suggest would be: `myuser $: who -T
vdevatman ? :0.0         2015-04-26 01:46 (:0.0)
vdevatman + pts/1        2015-04-26 18:46` , but that is only useful once it works, it isn't part of the solution.